# How many mono-red damage doubling effects are there?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

So I'm making a commander meme deck based around [Kumano, Master Yamabushi](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=kumano%2C%20master%20yamabushi). I was wondering how many damage doubling effects are there in mono-red. The current ones I can think of are: Furnace of Rath, Dictate of the Twin Gods, Angarath's Marauders, and Gratuitous Violence. The goal of the deck is, along with [Heartstone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=5164), be able to one shot people for just a red with Kumano. I would welcome any other suggestions for ways to increase Kumano's damage output or decrease the cost.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this, as there's nothing about it that's too broad. The set of relevant cards is small, and the question is completley answerable within our format. We have a specific problem and can provide adequate answers, and there are no multiple questions here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**10 that apply to your commander.**](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%22double+that+damage%22+ci%3Ar+f%3Acommander+%28-%22charging+tuskodon%22+-%22fire+servant%22+-%22goblin+charbelcher%22+-o%3A%22combat+damage%22%29) (11 if you're willing to do hijinx with [Goldnight Castigator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGoldnight%20Castigator%5d).)

Magic: the Gathering has highly standardised ways to word its effects, so when you see an effect you like and want to find more of it, you should search for the words you find in the effect that look like they're fairly unique to that effect. (Recognising which words those are can take some experience.)

You can search in either [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Default.aspx) (the official search engine), or a third party search engine like [Scryfall](https://scryfall.com/) or [MagicCards.info](https://magiccards.info/). I find these second two are far easier to compose searches in. I'm going to be referencing Scryfall below since it's my personal favorite.

If you search only for [`o:"double that damage"`](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%22double+that+damage%22+ci%3Ar+f%3Acommander) (within a color identity of red, and within the Commander format) you'll find 17 damage doubling effects.

The following don't actually work for your commander:

- [Charging Tuskodon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCharging%20Tuskodon%5d) and [Goblin Charbelcher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGoblin%20Charbelcher%5d) only double their own damage.
- [Fire Servant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFire%20Servant%5d) won't interact with Kumano.
- [Blind Fury](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlind%20Fury%5d), [Impulsive Maneuvers](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bImpulsive%20Maneuvers%5d), and [Inquisitor's Flail](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bInquisitor%27s%5d%2b%5bFlail%5d) only interact with combat damage (which won't count Kumano's ability).

[Goldnight Castigator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGoldnight%20Castigator%5d) doubles damage to you, but works if you you give it away with [Harmless Offering](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHarmless%20Offering%5d) or a similar spell.

We can [eliminate the ones that definitely don't work from the search results by name](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%22double+that+damage%22+ci%3Ar+f%3Acommander+%28-%22charging+tuskodon%22+-%22fire+servant%22+-%22goblin+charbelcher%22+-o%3A%22combat+damage%22%29) for our perusal.

---

You may also be interested in [**damage increasers**](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%22that+much+damage+plus%22+ci%3Ar+f%3Acommander), of which [Tok-Tok, Volcano Born](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTok-Tok%2c%20Volcano%20Born%5d) and [Embermaw Hellion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEmbermaw%20Hellion%5d) apply. (You can & should apply these before any damage doublers.)

Comment: Hm, you seem to still be including Goldnight Castigator, which only helps if you somehow give it to your opponent. Also Blind Fury only doubles damage to creatures, won't help one-shot an opponent. But I do agree that this kind of query is how I'd find the candidates!

Comment: I think including Goldnight Castigator is appropriate. It helps the answer remain objective, and allows the reader judge which effects are too difficult to pull off in a real match.

Comment: Doesn't Blind Fury apply only to creatures, and therefore not work for targeting a player?

Comment: Cool, this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

By my count there are 10 (11 if you count the double-printed card as two).
You can find them when you follow [this link](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[%22deals%20double%22]+[%22source%22]&color=+@(+[R])).
You can use the Gatherer to search for such cards, as shown here.